# How do I retrieve and output only the latest Facebook comment on my post using javascript (and Graph API?)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an html page which needs to be able to retrieve only the latest comment for a Facebook post. I would like to have it auto refresh and again re-load only the latest comment every 10 seconds. I am imagining that this would be done using the Facebook Graph API, Javascript and possibly an Ajax call?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"re-load only the latest comment every 10 seconds"_ - forget about that, you will run into the [rate limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) faster that you'll be able to say, _Yeah, I guess in hindsight that was a rather dumb idea ..._

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, looks like I get 200 calls per hour for the FB app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to install the Javascript SDK and get an access token...

comments order has 3 (ranked, chronological (oldest first), reverse_chronological (newest first)

then include the limit modifier (to only retrieve one) from there the response should be enough to satisfy your needs

```
FB.api("/{post-id}/comments?order=reverse_chronological&limit=1", function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm up and running with the latest comments once I added the SDK and Token.